# More agony resistance from infusions

Tags: guild-wars-2

With Fine Infusions such as as [Precise Infusion](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Precise_Infusion), you just double-click it and apply to the ascended ring, right?

However, can you add more infusions to the infused ring which results to +10 AR (+5 & +5)? Is it possible?
I'm asking this because I'm wondering how people got 40+ etc. AR. How can I get more agony resistance? Is there a maximum AR for each accessory?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arqade! Please only ask one question per topic! I've removed the 'Bonus Question' from this, but feel free to ask it separately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!

To do so, you need to "infuse" the ring via the Mystic Forge, a process which will provide the ring an inherent +5 Agony Resistance (which means you can slot an infusion for a grand total of +10).

The recipe is:

1. The ring to upgrade
2. 1 [Shard of Crystallized Mists Essence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Shard_of_Crystallized_Mists_Essence)
3. 3 [Glob of Coagulated Mists Essence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Coagulated_Mists_Essence)
4. 5 [Vial of Condensed Mists Essence](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Vial_of_Condensed_Mists_Essence)

Alternatively, the wiki mentions that pre-infused rings can drop starting in Tier 3 (20+) daily reward chests.

**Currently, the maximum Agony Resistance is 45,** 10 each from an Ascended Back and Ring(x2), and 5 each from ascended accessories and from an ascended Amulet. (These can't yet be infused)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. So to get those mist essences, I just need to rely on MF and luck in running 1-20+ level dungeons, right? And for "1. The ring to upgrade," my Precise Infusion has to be inside already, right?

Comment: @ton Yup! I believe there are also mystic forge recipes to transform globs to shards and vice versa. As to the latter question, as far as I'm aware, you don't need an infusion in your item to infuse it, and infusing an uninfused item will leave its infusion empty, so you will need to reinfuse your new, infused, item.